# Where is the syntax error in this Julia function

Tags: julia

I have the following code:

```
using Winston

function testConjecGeneral(n,numTrials)
    rangeVec = 2.0
    uppBound = zeros(length(rangeVec), 1)
    count = 1
    for alpha = rangeVec
        uppBound(count) = n*renyi([0.25, 0.5, 0.25], alpha)
        println("Upper bound: $(uppBound(count))")
       count = count+1
    end
end
```

When I try to load the code, using include("testConjecGeneral.jl") at the command prompt, I get ERROR: syntax: missing comma or ) in argument list
while loading /home/ganesh/UROP/YuryJulia/testConjecGeneral.jl, in expression starting on line 3

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Your question Title is not appropriate... Please make changes...

Comment: Any title suggestions? I do agree that the title is not good, but since I find the error message so cryptic, I can't think of a better one.

Answer (score 2):

```
uppBound(count) = n*renyi([0.25, 0.5, 0.25], alpha)
```

doesn't look right to me. zeros returns an array and the right way to reference an array item is with square brackets. As written now it looks like it's trying call a function. Does changing that line to:

```
uppBound[count] = n*renyi([0.25, 0.5, 0.25], alpha)
```

fix the problem?

Comment: No, it does not. The same error message still appears. I wonder why it is flagging line 3.

Comment: Your println also dererences uppbound incorrectly. At this point in my debugging I usually start commenting lines to see which one is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks. I am coming in from MATLAB; forgot about the () vs [] for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a syntax error, but `rangeVec` is not what you seem to think it is. You assign to `rangeVec` the `Float64` value `2.0` and then you treat `rangeVec` like an `Array`, calling `length(rangeVec)` and looping over `alpha = rangeVec`. Do you mean for `rangeVec` to be an `Array` or a `Float64`?

Comment: I know, it is just for testing purposes. In MATLAB, this kind of style does not result in any errors (rangeVec can be an array or a single double). I managed to fix the problem, though I don't remember what exactly I did.